# Change color of CheckboxColumn if checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, checkbox

Searched a lot about this problem but never found a answer, that solved it.

I´ve got the following CheckboxColumn in a WPF datagrid:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Erledigt" Binding="{Binding Path=erledigt}"  />
```

The variable `erledigt` contains 0 or 1. Now I want, that if the Checkbox is checked, the cellbackground is green. 
Hopelessly searched for a checked property. How can I manage this?

Comment: I would recommend a boolean datatype instead of some kind of number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `CellStyle` to the column in which you just use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) on `erledigt`, you don't need the `IsChecked` property itself. Using the `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` you should be able to add a normal [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx) on `IsChecked` as the style should be one applied the `CheckBoxes`, however the scope would also be limited to the `CheckBoxes` themselves and not the cell.

---

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding erledigt}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

You can also bind to the `CheckBox.IsChecked` from the cell level, this has the effect that the colour will be changing right away instead of after committing the change which then affects the bound property. To do so change the trigger in the `CellStyle` to this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content.IsChecked,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             Value="True">
```